# Masking the navigation sounds in IE using AutoIT?

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, audio

I wrote a program using AutoIT to fetch information from a number of websites using Internet Explorer. AutoIT is capable of hiding the window so that it is not visible, however when I navigate to a new website on that hidden window I still get the IE navigation sounds (button click sound, etc.).

How can I disable the sounds from playing using AutoIT?
(Muting the computer, or altering settings in the control panel would not be ideal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could temporary change the click sound to an empty sound and then restore it after the navigation.
Its stored in the registry here:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating.current

Just create a new stringvalue or modify the existing (Default) to an empty string value to mute the sound.

But first read the key so that you can put it back to whatever filename was there before.

Its not a perfect solution but it works. The obvious drawbacks with this is if a user change the sound exact between when you read the value and then put it back, you could overwrite the new value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this variant too. Just have your hidden explorer window and access the DOM and create an iframe as described in this example: 
http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/11/30/